# pass parameter when you call the event in main

Tags: c#

I have the OnGoal event and i have two teams from custom class Team how can i pass the Team typed object to event to change the score value i'm confused here's my code:

```
public delegate void  TeamDeligate(Team _team);
public  void Game_Start(object starttime,Team _away,Team _home)
{
    string text;
    var game = new Game();
    DateTime StartTime = (DateTime)starttime;
    Console.WriteLine("Game Starts!");
    Console.Write("Q1:blablabla?");
    Show_Left(StartTime);
    text=Console.ReadLine();
    if (text == "goal away") game.OnGoal += game_OnGoal(_away);

}

void game_OnGoal(Team _team)
{
    _team.Score++;
}
```

And here's is my Team class:

```
public class Game
{
    public Team Home { get; set; }
    public Team Away { get; set; }
    public Team Win { get; set; }

    public event TeamDeligate OnGoal;

}
```

Comment: Where are you firing your event?

Comment: Well this code even doesn't compile. Here: `game.OnGoal += game_OnGoal(_away);` you are confusing event handler registration with a method call. In your present code, there's currently absolutely no sign you should use events. Rather learn the very basics of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're using events in incorrect way. In book ["C# in a Nutshell"](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781449334192) there is a great example of standart Event pattern implementation:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781449334192/events/id4257031

Passings arguments to event handler, event source, event args it's all there.